# Enforcing implementation of functionality for ActiveRecord subclasses

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I am quite unsure how to implement the following situation.

1. ActiveRecord Base class which represents the table in database
2. Subclasses of that Base class where I want to enforce the implementation of some functions

Implementing an Interface in the subclasses does not feel right and maybe I want to use inheritance.

I would like to use an abstract class for the base class, but I cannot instantiate that class, so I would need another concrete class between the two layers just to make database operations (AR).

What would be the best way?

Comment: Why would you need an abstract class here ???

Comment: I do not need it, but some functions have to be implemented in every subclass and I do not want to use an interface.

Comment: So, what is the problem ? You could extend ActiveRecord, or use traits.

Comment: I do extend from ActiveRecord. It's no big problem, just wanted it to make cleaner and more understandable for other developers and, therefore my wish for an abstract class with some abstract methods. But ok, now I changed the base class to be non abstract.